# Processing tables in parallel using Azure Data Factory, single pipeline, single Databricks Notebook?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks, spark-notebook

I want to transform a list of tables in parallel using Azure Data Factory and one single Databricks Notebook.

I already have an Azure Data Factory (ADF) pipeline that receives a list of tables as a parameter, sets each table from the table list as a variable, then calls one single notebook (that performs simple transformations) and passes each table in series to this notebook. The problem is that it transforms the tables in series (one after the other) and not in parallel (all tables at the same time). I need the tables to be processed in parallel.

**So, my questions are: 
1) Is it possible to trigger the same Databricks notebook multiple times at the exact same point in time (each time with a different table as a parameter) from Azure Data Factory?
2) If yes, then what do I need to change in my pipeline or notebook to make it work?**

Thanks in advance :)

**Parameters**

[image: ADF Parameters]

**Variables**

[image: variables]

**Set Table Variables and Notebook**

[image]

**Configure Sequential**

[image: Configure Sequential]

**Sequential Unchecked with Batch Count = blank**

When configured as "sequential" and Batch Count = blank, and pass two tables, the pipeline runs "successfully" but only one table is transformed (even if I add multiple tables in the table list). "Set variable" correctly shows twice, once for each table. But Orchestrate shows twice for the same table.

[image]

**Sequential Unchecked with Batch Count = 2**

When configured as "sequential" and Batch Count = 2, and pass two tables, the pipeline fails on the second iteration, but it also tries transforming the same table two times. "Set variable" correctly shows twice, once for each table. But Orchestrate shows twice for the same table.

[image: Sequential Unchecked with Batch Count = 2]

**Sequential Checked or Batch Count =1**

If I leave Sequential Checked or Batch Count =1, then the pipeline runs correctly and performs transformations on all tables, but the processing occurs in series (as expected). Example below for 5 tables.

[image: Sequential Checked or Batch Count =1]

[image: Example of Sequential Checked or Batch Count =1]

**Set Variable Task**

[image: Set Variable Task Overview]

Variable table passed with value @item()

[image: Variable table passed with value @item()]

Variable "table" defined as string

[image: Variable "table"]

Parameter "table_list"

[image: Parameter "table_list"]

Pipeline Run Parameters

[image: Pipeline Run Parameters]

Comment: Having multiple executions of a single notebook is definitely possible. We use this all the time. Could you show what you're doing in the set variables task and how you pass the variable to the notebook?

Comment: @SimonZeinstra Thank you for your reply! I have added the details of set variables and how I pass it to the notebook in the description of the problem (above). I look forward to your feedback. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it using "Lookup" to a SQL tables instead of "Set Variable". The picture below shows a run of 5 tables in parallel using one single notebook.

[image]

Comment: Yeah, sorry I didn't reply before. The problem with your previous solution was the variable that you were using. The variable exists on the pipeline level, not within the foreach scope. So when you run a parallel foreach, the value of the variable will be the value that is set by the last exectution of a set-variable activity. You did not need the variable in that solution, you could have used @item() directly in your Databricks activity. Same way as you did in your sql solution.